# Legendre symbol proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that if $a$ is a quadratic residue of the odd prime $p$, then the solutions of $x^2\equiv{a}\pmod {p}$ are $x\equiv{\pm a^{n+1}}\pmod {p}$  if 
$p=4n+3$.

Proof
Assume $p=4n+3$ and $x^2\equiv{a}\pmod {p}$.  $p=4n+3 \Longleftrightarrow n=(p-3)/4$.
To see if $\pm{a}\pmod{p}$ Plugging it into $x^2\equiv{a}\pmod {p}$ we get 
${(\pm a^{n+1})}^2\equiv {a}\pmod{p}$ We plug $n=(p-3)/4$. We get ${(\pm a^{\frac{P-3}{4}+1})}^2\equiv {a}\pmod{p}$ which is  ${(\pm a^{\frac{P+1}{4}})}^2\equiv {a}\pmod{p}$
which is ${( a^{\frac{P+1}{2}})}\equiv {a}\pmod{p}$ But $\frac{p-1}{2}$ is odd since $p=4n+3$ is an odd prime. Let $\frac{p-1}{2}=2k+1$ where $k$ is a positive integer. Now we get 
${(a^{{2k+1}})}\equiv {a}\pmod{p}$ Which is $(a^{k})^2*a\equiv {a}\pmod{p}$ Divide both sides by $a$ but since $(a,p)=1$ the modulus stays the same.  Since $(a^k)^2\equiv {1}\pmod{p}$ since it is of the form  $x^2\equiv{a}\pmod {p}$ it follows $x\equiv{\pm a^{n+1}}\pmod {p}$ 
Not sure if I have this right or that $(a,p)=1$.

Comment: What exactly is the question? It's not easy to follow.

Comment: yes my bad. Im supposed to show that both congruence's are solutions.

Answer (score 1):

All congruences are done modulo $p$.  Assume that $x = \pm a^{n+1}$.  Then,

\begin{align*}
x^2 \equiv a^{2n + 2} = a^{\frac{4n+4}{2}} = a^{\frac{p+1}{2}}.
\end{align*}

We need to show that $a^{\frac{p+1}{2}} \equiv a$ for all $p = 4n + 3$. Note that $x^2 \equiv b^2 \implies x \equiv \pm b$ since the integers modulo $p$ forms a [field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28mathematics%29#Finite_fields).  Since $\left( a^{\frac{p+1}{2}}\right)^2 \equiv a^2$, by Fermat's little theorem, we really need to show that $a^{\frac{p+1}{2}} \not\equiv -a$.  However, since $p = 4n +3$, and since $a$ is a quadratic residue, then $-a$ is not.  Above we showed that $a^{\frac{p+1}{2}}$ is a quadratic residue.  Hence $-a$ and $a^{\frac{p+1}{2}}$ cannot be equal, and thus we arrive at $a^{\frac{p+1}{2}} \equiv a$ as desired.

I should note that my "proof" is not as self-contained as I would like.  In particular, it may or may not be clear why it is true that if $a$ is a quadratic residue $\pmod p$, then $-a$ is a quadratic nonresidue.  It may also not be clear that the integers modulo $p$ form a field.  Because of this lack of self-containment, perhaps there is a more elementary answer.